# Updating value in array updates all values with the last inserted value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have two arrays, one with quantities called `aantal` and one with products called `producten`.

Producten:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Tegel zwart
            [2] => Zwarte tegel 2x2m
            [3] => 47,5
            [4] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => Tegel lichtgrijs
            [2] => Lichtgrijze tegel 2x2m
            [3] => 40,5
            [4] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Tegel zwart
            [2] => Zwarte tegel 2x2m
            [3] => 47,5
            [4] => 25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => Tegel lichtgrijs
            [2] => Lichtgrijze tegel 2x2m
            [3] => 40,5
            [4] => 25
        )

)
```

Aantal:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 27
    [3] => 25
)
```

I want to update each quantity according to the $_GET values from the url with the following code:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['producten'] as $key => $product){
    //$_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = '';
    $number = str_replace(',', '.', $product[3]);
    $sum+= $number;
    if(!empty($_GET['aantal'])){
        foreach($_GET['aantal'] as $keyaantal => $aantal){
            $_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = $_GET['aantal'][$keyaantal];
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = '1';
    }
}
```

This is the form with the html:

```
<form action="cart.php">
<?php foreach ( $_SESSION['producten'] as $row){

    if(!empty($_GET['aantal'])){
        $aantalwaarde = $row[4];
    }else{
        $aantalwaarde = 1;
    }

    // if($row != ){

    // }
    ?>


        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[0] // ID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[1] // Product_naam; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[2] // Beschrijving; ?></td> 
            <td><input name="aantal[]" type="number" value="<?PHP echo $aantalwaarde; ?>"></td> 
            <td>€<?php echo $row[3] // Prijs; ?></td>   

            <?php $total = $total + intval($row[3]); ?>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Updaten"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Totaalprijs</td>
            <td></td> 
            <td>€<?php echo $sum // Prijs; ?></td>   

        </tr>

</form>
```

Why if I click the update button, it updates the last inserted values for all products? For example if I set the last quantity input at 25 and the one before it at 10, all products have a quantity for 25.

How can I fix that?

Comment: As mentioned, you are overlooking the fact these are arrays. Strange things can happen in a loop. Add some debugging code at crucial points to check the values you are working with, they are often not the ones you think you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner foreach loop is the problem. You're going through all the quantities instead of picking the related one. So when the loop ends you're always left with the last one being added to your session.

I can't test right now but I think you should change

```
foreach($_GET['aantal'] as $keyaantal => $aantal){ 
   $_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = $_GET['aantal'][$keyaantal]; 
}
```

to

```
$_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = $_GET['aantal'][$key];
```

That way, you select the matching key for both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You code has a big flaw. First, you iterate through the entire `producten` array. Within this array, you loop through the `aantal` array and update the values. That really doesn't make sense, you don't need that second loop at all. You can replace this entire part ...

```
foreach($_GET['aantal'] as $keyaantal => $aantal){
    $_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = $_GET['aantal'][$keyaantal];
}
```

... with this ...

```
$_SESSION['producten'][$key][4] = $_GET['aantal'][$key];
```

That should do the trick.

The problem with your loop was is that you iterated through the array and updated the value of your `['producten'][$key][4]` with each iteration. That means the last value you're stuck with is always the last one.